# Primefaces gmap rendering

Tags: google-maps, primefaces

Hello I have been reading the documentation about gmap in Primefaces, I put according the documentation:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

I replaced YOUR_API_KEY by my google API key and removed the space between ? and key

and

```
<p:gmap center="41.381542, 2.122893" zoom="15" type="hybrid" style="width:600px;height:400px" />
```

but when I rendered the page there was an error:

> The reference to entity "callback" must end with the ';' delimiter.

So I searched on google and I replaced `&` by `&amp;` and the line was

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&amp;callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Then I have the error

> Attribute name "async" associated with an element type "script" must be followed by the ' = ' character.

Reading on google I changed it as following

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&amp;callback=initMap" async="async" defer></script>
```

then I have the error

> Attribute name "defer" associated with an element type "script" must be followed by the ' = ' character.

Reading on google I changed it again

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&amp;callback=initMap" async="async" defer="defer" ></script>
```

Then I have these errors:

> ReferenceError: google is not defined
>
> Uncaught exception: InvalidValueError: initMap is not a function

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The below should work

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY></script>
```